# How to move an already uploaded image into an album in Imgur

Tags: images, album, imgur

I can't seem to find a way to move my uploaded images into an album on Imgur.
Am I missing something? Is it not possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to do the following:

- Click on *Albums*
- Click on the album you want add images to
- select *Add or Remove images*

A *Select images for this album* pop-up then appears. The boxes on the left allow to add images that are not in albums, or all images.
So click on *Non-album images*, select the ones you want moved into the selected album, then click *Save*.

[image]

Comment: Than you worked for me!

Comment: Where is this "Albums" button you speak of?

Answer (score 1):

according to a help article located at https://help.imgur.com/hc/en-us/articles/203921555-How-do-I-add-an-existing-image-to-an-existing-album you may add an existing image to an existing album or to a new album. Please note that you can also share your album via link or HTML embed code using "Share this Album" section located on your right.

I am not yet sure if it is possible to add other public images on imgur.com ( which someone else uploaded or you anonymously uploaded ) to your new or existing album. But I wish if there was a way to do so.

Also note that you can control the privacy of your album by using "Change Album Settings" link as shown below.

[image]